# Play WS SSL acceptAnyCertificate=true issue

Tags: ssl, https, playframework, ssl-certificate

We are using Play WS SSL firsttime and `play.ws.ssl.loose.acceptAnyCertificate: 'true'` config which intends to be for disabling Hostname Verification.

But for some reason I see , it still does the host verification and I see the following warnings.

```
August 3rd 2017, 15:02:25.084   *** ClientKeyExchange, DH
August 3rd 2017, 15:02:25.083   *** Certificate chain
August 3rd 2017, 15:02:25.083   ***
August 3rd 2017, 15:02:25.083   Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
August 3rd 2017, 15:02:25.083   0080: 72 70 72 69 73 65 43 41   30 31                    rpriseCA01
August 3rd 2017, 15:02:25.083   [read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
August 3rd 2017, 15:02:25.083   0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
August 3rd 2017, 15:02:25.083   <Empty>
August 3rd 2017, 15:02:25.083   *** ServerHelloDone
```

From my understanding,

```
play.ws.ssl.loose.acceptAnyCertificate: 'true'  --> Strict validation
play.ws.ssl.loose.acceptAnyCertificate: 'false' --> Loose Validation
```

When we set the flag to `false` , it was able to identity server cert from keystore and does cert validation and other checks, also the handshake was happening as expected.

Where as when we set the loose config with flag `true`, it's NOT able to identify the server cert and throws `no suitable certificate found` warning and handshake fails.

For me it doesn't make any sense as it was working in the strict case but fails in the loose case which is strange behaviour.

I can say when the flag is set to `true`, play uses JDK's SSLEngine implementation but some other implementation in case the flag is `false`

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Suresh

Answer (score 3):

`play.ws.ssl.loose.acceptAnyCertificate: 'true'` will disable certificate validation, and that is something you should not do unless you understand what are the implications (read [Play Framework - Loose Options](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/LooseSSL) for more information).

To disable hostname verification, use this instead:

```
play.ws.ssl.loose.disableHostnameVerification=true
```